# Shell script with regex in if statement gives error

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I am new to shell scripting, and I am trying to get a regex written in an if statement. I am using bash shell on mac osx 10.6.8. Here is the code I am trying to run

```
#!/bin/bash

line="A903      ATGCGTCGTC"

if [[ $line =~ ^\w+\t[GATCN]+ ]]; then
        echo "Exiting ... Check File"
        exit 0
else
        echo "File ... OK"
fi
```

I should get "Exiting ... Check File" as output, instead I get "File ... OK". What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure that `\w` and `\t` are valid in a bash regular expression.  If I replace those with `[A-Z0-9]+` and a literal tab, it Just Works.

Comment: Ok... well can you point me to a textbook or site where I can find valid bash regex? Thanks. I put together this code by searching some stack overflow posts and others elsewhere

Comment: The ['bash' tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has good resources for you. I personally like Bash Hackers and the BashGuide by Lhunath.

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me

```
#!/bin/bash

line="A903      ATGCGTCGTC"

if [[ $line =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]+[GATCN]+ ]]; then
        echo "Exiting ... Check File"
        exit 0
else
        echo "File ... OK"
fi
```

Found info about POSIX regex [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17046.html)

Comment: Apparently POSIX regex characters allow better portability because they conform to your locale. Annoying that they are so long, but you could store the regex in its own variable on a different line to cut down on line length.

Comment: Yes it works for me. Thanks. But, God this is so complex. Can't I get around the POSIX regex somehow? Or is this something terminal on a mac comes with. Thnaks

Comment: +1, but it's worth noting that `[[:space:]]` is the equivalent of `\s` and therefore matches more than just `\t` - if you wanted to match only the latter, you could splice in a bash tab literal (`$'\t'`): `if [[ $line =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+$'\t'[GATCN]+ ]]; then`